# Remove table duplicates under certain conditions

Tags: kdb

I have a table like below that shows me some pnl by instrument (code) for some shifts, maturity, etc.

Instrument 123 appears two times (2 sets of shift, booknumber, insmat but different pnl). I would like to clean the table to only keep the first set (3 first rows).

```
> code | shift | pnl | booknumber | insmat
  123    -20%    5     1234         2021.01.29
  123    -0%     7     1234         2021.01.29
  123    +20%    9     1234         2021.01.29
  123    -20%    4     1234         2021.01.29
  123    -0%     6     1234         2021.01.29
  123    +20%    8     1234         2021.01.29
  456    -20%    1     1234         2021.01.29
  456    -0%     2     1234         2021.01.29
  456    +20%    3     1234         2021.01.29
```

If there were no shifts involved I would do something like this:

```
select first code, first pnl, first booknumber, first insmat by code from t
```

Would love to hear if you have a solution!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the shift pattern is consistently 3 shifts, you could use

```
q)select from t where 0=i mod 3
code shift pnl booknumber insmat
------------------------------------
123  20    5   1234       2021.01.29
123  20    4   1234       2021.01.29
456  -20   1   1234       2021.01.29
```

Alternative solution with an `fby`

```
q)select from t where shift=(first;shift)fby code
code shift pnl booknumber insmat
------------------------------------
123  20    5   1234       2021.01.29
123  20    4   1234       2021.01.29
456  -20   1   1234       2021.01.29
```

This will only work if the first shift value is unique within the shift pattern however.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second option works like a charm!